# Redirection to a blank page after searching on Google with the search bar of Firefox

Tags: web-browser, firefox, url-redirection, browser-hijacking

Today I tried to use the search bar in the top-right side of Firefox (ver 65.0 64-bit on Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia 64-bit), and the search bar contains "search Google in Traditional Chinese".
[image: My search bar setting]

When I use it to search Google with a keyword (台中市; lit. Taichung City), it will redirects to https://www.google.com.tw/search?hl=zh-TW&q=%E8%87%BA%E4%B8%AD%E5%B8%82&meta=lr%3Dlang_zh-TW . However, the browser will be redirected to a blank page unexpectedly during the loading of seach result, and using the search bar in Firefox with privacy mode and cleaning all history (eg. cookies, website setting, caches) except the URL-browsing records did't fixed it. However, open the URL shown above with Chrome (ver. 71.0.3578.98) won't let the browser show the blank page.

I viewed the source code of the blank page ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/yrKj3s64)) and I found that it contains <del>some strange js script</del> js that is similar to that in other Google search result pages.

Besides, when I searched with the search in Google website (http://www.google.com.tw), it was once redirected to https://www.google.com.tw/search?source=hp&ei=2vSDXM-CGZbo8wXplaLwCQ&q=%E8%87%BA%E4%B8%AD%E5%B8%82&btnK=Google+%E6%90%9C%E5%B0%8B&oq=%E8%87%BA%E4%B8%AD%E5%B8%82&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.1395.2590..3343...0.0..0.135.620.8j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i131j0i7i30.rSZxmKd8OpQ, and then was redirected to a blank page ([source code](https://pastebin.com/zGnv7KUK)). However, while searching with the Google website on another time, it was redirected to https://www.google.com.tw/search?hl=zh-TW&source=hp&ei=mvWDXIXVMoyR8wXYv5J4&q=%E8%87%BA%E4%B8%AD%E5%B8%82&btnK=Google+%E6%90%9C%E5%B0%8B&oq=%E8%87%BA%E4%B8%AD%E5%B8%82&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.687.1474..2098...0.0..0.120.628.8j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i131j0i7i30.EBfKLNmJp6Y , and no blank page shown.

Does it means that my Firefox is hijacked (eg. the options for search bar is modified by malware) or it's a browser or website bug?

The extensions used in my Firefox is shown below:
[image: Firefox extensions that I use]